# LsaICryptUnprotectData vs CryptUnprotectData function

Tags: c++

basically  LsaICryptUnprotectData is undocumented and found in lsasrv.dll and CryptUnprotectData function is found in crypt32.lib. Do they serve the same purpose?

Comment: Is `CryptUnprotectData` not adequate for your needs? Given the choice, who ya gonna call?

Comment: I am trying to decrypt/encrypt network domain passwords.